# Which is the correct folder to store images used in vignettes for R packages ?

Tags: r, knitr, devtools, r-package

I am writing a vignette for my R package. I want to include a .jpg image on the .Rmd file that will generate the pdf vignette. The question is: where should I store this image?

I am using the packages `devtools` and `knitr` to generate vignettes (following the advise from @hadley book [link](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/vignettes.html)). Therefore, I have the folder vignettes in my package structure. Should I just include the file there? Or should I include the image on a new folder inside **'inst/images'**, as suggested for external data used in vignettes (also recomended by @hadley: [link](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html))?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.
Cheers

Comment: IMO it's pretty clearly described in the [Writing R Extensions manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Writing-package-vignettes): "All other files needed to re-make the vignettes (such as LaTeX style files, BibTeX input files and files for any figures not created by running the code in the vignette) must be in the vignette source directory."

Comment: Thanks! That is correct! Could you add this as a answer?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's pretty clearly described in the [Writing R Extensions manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Writing-package-vignettes):

> All other files needed to re-make the vignettes (such as LaTeX style
>   files, BibTeX input files and files for any figures not created by
>   running the code in the vignette) must be in the vignette source
>   directory.

Comment: No problem at all, happy to help, @GustavoBPaterno :)

Answer (score 11):

It is also appropriate to put them in the "man/figures" folder -- this also holds for images you may have in your README.

See comment by Hadley on github issue that happens to reference guidelines: https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/issues/280#issue-213905707

Answer (score -9):

I'm thinking that jpgs would fall under Hadley's advice [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html#data-extdata)

> If you want to store binary data and make it available to the user,
>   put it in data/. This is the best place to put example datasets.