# Save images for plotting purposes in R packages

Tags: r, image, data-visualization, packaging

I need to use a few images, instead for vertices shapes, for plotting graphs with the use of `igraph`. The above are part of a function which is part of an `R package`. For the packaging I use `roxygen`. I have already stored my datasets as recommended in the `data` directory, however I haven't managed so far to find out the proper place to store `images` that are used in functions in the package.

The closest answer that I managed to find so far, is [Which is the correct folder to store images used in vignettes for R packages ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287633/which-is-the-correct-folder-to-store-images-used-in-vignettes-for-r-packages) which is not my case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inst/` directory.

*References*:

- https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories

  > The contents of the inst subdirectory will be copied recursively to the installation directory.
- http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html

  > You are free to put anything you like in `inst/` ...

Comment: Thank you! It was what I was looking for and in combination with how to read the file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463103/inst-and-extdata-folders-in-r-packaging I had the whole set of answers that I needed to proceed.